# Do Core Chip bonus effects count towards Merc Group strength requirements?

Tags: xenoblade-chronicles-2

Some Merc Group missions have requirements that can only be met by blades with a minimum level of strength. Does this strength requirement include bonus effects from Core Chips?

For example, the [Magnet Chip's special effects chart](https://xenoblade.fandom.com/wiki/Magnet_Chip#Special_Effects_) says it will increase Strength by 50 if it's used on a blade that uses Whipswords or Dual Scythes as a weapon. Would that bonus strength count for Merc Mission requirements?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a case of XC2's unfriendly terminology biting you.

A Core Chip's bonus strength does not apply to Merc Mission strength requirements because the two uses of the word "strength" here are referring to two distinct and entirely unrelated things.

- When Core Chips modify "Strength", they're modifying the Driver's Strength stat, thus increasing the amount of physical damage dealt when that Blade is active.
- When a Merc Mission is asking for a Blade's "Strength", they're checking the Blade's Strength stat, which is the number of unlocked nodes in their Affinity Chart.

Comment: Where is a driver's strength stat shown?

Comment: Just on their main Character Setup screen I believe, though since core chips are weapon-specific I don't think this screen would show their effects.

Answer (score 0):

No, bonus effects from Core Chips do not count towards Merc Mission strength requirements.

My blade Roc has a base Strength of 22. After equipping them with a Magnet Chip to raise their strength by 50, they still did not satisfy the Strength 35+ requirement for the *Big Ship Escort* mission in Alrest.

[image: Roc equipped with a magnet chip]

[image: Roc not meeting the Strength 35+ requirement]